# Free or demo iis server to test

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, windows-server-2008, kentico

I am coming from a Linux and Mac environment but never really got into MS products. I wanted to test Kentico but it only runs on .net

Is there anything like xampp or lamp for ms? I don't really need a public facing solution just need to be able to run the software to see how well it is over some of the php CMS solutions

By the way I only have Mac no windows machines

Comment: An alternative to installing a trial of Kentico is to get a [Hosted Trial](http://www.kentico.com/download-demo/hosted-trial). It lasts 7 days, and saves you from installing anything

Comment: You can register for the free Visual Studio Dev Essentials and get some free Azure credits to run Windows in the Azure cloud for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup virtual machine applications in you mac and installing windows OS with IIS.
below are the Virtual applications available for Mac

1. QEMU (Free)
2. [Boot Camp (Free)](https://support.apple.com/boot-camp)
3. [VirtualBox (Free)](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
4. VMware Workstation Player (Free)